# iTunesConnect Users and Roles

Tags: app-store-connect

Man this sucks....I am trying to set up ApplePay using stripe. It's documentation states I need to log into iTunesConnect and click Users and Roles.....

https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay/web

And when looking at the actual Apple docs, it says the same thing:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SettingUpUserAccounts.html

and here:

https://developer.apple.com/support/apple-pay-sandbox/

But, when I log into iTunesConnect I see this screen:

[image]

I just can't seem to find where I am supposed to find users and roles.....
Does anyone know how I can get to this elusive screen?

Comment: I am also having the same issue, I am a team agent of Enterprise Developer account. Did you find the solution can you please help if this is resolved for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are not a team agent for your developer account or you are not added as a user to itunes connect.

The Team Agent of the apple developer program will have access to add other users and assign roles to them. Please refer to https://www.meatti.com/blog/how-to-create-itunes-connect-limited-user/ on how to add user and assign roles in iTunes connect.

Refer to https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/ to know about the iTunes connect and developer account roles in detail.

Answer (score -1):

I'd look down the `Apps` route there.

If this is your first interaction with iTunes Connect, there will be a certain amount of setup you need to do before you get to view/edit users and roles.

Answer (score -1):

It's because you have to register as a developer. Once I had done that, the options showed.

Comment: how to register as a developer in iTunes connect